# Drop columns that aren't common between two dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes that have many columns in column but a few that do not exist in both.  I would like to create a dataframe that only has the columns that are in common between both dataframes.  So for example:

```
list(df1)
['Survived', 'Age', 'Title_Mr', 'Title_Mrs', 'Title_Captain']
list(df2)
['Survived', 'Age', 'Title_Mr', 'Title_Mrs', 'Title_Countess']
```

And I would like to go to:

```
['Survived', 'Age', 'Title_Mr', 'Title_Mrs']
```

Since `Title_Mr` and `Title_Mrs` are in both `df1` and `df2`.  I've figured out how to do it by manually entering in the columns names like so:

```
df1 = df1.drop(['Title_Captain'], axis=1)
```

But I'd like to find a more robust solution where I don't have to manually enter the column names.  Suggestions?

Comment: Can't you use sets and intersections? For e.g 
`>>> l1 = ['Survived', 'Age', 'Title_Mr', 'Title_Mrs', 'Title_Captain']

>>> l2=['Survived', 'Age', 'Title_Mr', 'Title_Mrs', 'Title_Countess']

>>> list(set(l1).intersection(set(l2)))
['Title_Mr', 'Age', 'Title_Mrs', 'Survived']
`

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure.  Just to clarify - I'm working with dataframes not lists, I'm just printing the columns from the dataframes to show what columns are present.  Would this change anything?

Comment: @linuxfan, you don't need to make `l2` a set, `set.intersection` takes any iterable, you could also use the `df1[df1.isin(df2)]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the comments of @linuxfan and @PadraicCunningham we can get a list of common columns:

```
common_cols = list(set(df1.columns).intersection(df2.columns))
```

Edit: @AdamHughes' answer made me consider preserving the column order. If that is important you could do this instead:

```
common_cols = [col for col in set(df1.columns).intersection(df2.columns)]
```

To get another DataFrame with just those columns you use that list to select only those columns from `df1`:

```
df3 = df1[common_cols]
```

According to http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html:

> You can pass a list of columns to `[]` to select columns in that order.
>   If a column is not contained in the DataFrame, an exception will be
>   raised.

Answer (score 2):

`df1 = df1.drop([col for col in df1.columns if col in df1.columns and col in df2.columns], axis=1)`

Comment: +1 more straightforward than my approach and preserves column order

Comment: Thanks.  Appreciate the upvote because I finally have enough rep to comment on threads!

Comment: You're welcome. Oh, I just noticed there is a minor syntax error. The list-comprehension should instead be: `[col for col in df1.columns if col in df1.columns and col in df2.columns]`

Comment: I was never able to get this method to work (even with bernie's update).

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need to drop the columns, just select the columns of interest:

```
In [204]:

df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Survived', 'Age', 'Title_Mr', 'Title_Mrs', 'Title_Captain'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Survived', 'Age', 'Title_Mr', 'Title_Mrs', 'Title_Countess'])
# create a list of the common columns using set and intersection
common_cols=list(set.intersection(set(df1), set(df2)))
# use this list to perform column selection
df1[common_cols]
['Title_Mr', 'Age', 'Survived', 'Title_Mrs']
Out[204]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Title_Mr, Age, Survived, Title_Mrs]
Index: []
```